# Integration Test a Reactive Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

TLDR; How do you test a Reactive Function composition using the Test Binder?

I have a Spring Cloud Stream that uses Reactive Functions and I don't know how to test it. I don't see any official docs on how to do an Integration Test from input source to output destination binder.

In my specific case, I am connecting a Spring Integration flow using a Reactive Supplier and the `IntegrationReactiveUtils.messageChannelToFlux()` pattern. This works in a development environment - I can pull messages from RabbitMQ using the Spring Integration Flow and they enter the SCSt.

My SCSt has several function chained together, each one is reactive. They are composed like `func1|func2|func3`. I verified this works with a dev Rabbit (source) and Kafka (Destination).

I can't seem to figure out how to test this, and there doesn't seem to be any official documentation on testing a complete reactive stream. Right now I have code that roughly looks like this:

```java
@Autowired
MessageChannel inputChannel;

@Autowired
private OutputDestination output;

@Test
void myTest() {
    //omitted prep of var 'messageToSend'
    this.inputChannel.send(messageToSend);
    var outputMessage = output.receive(5000);
    Assertions.assertNotNull(outputMessage.getPayload());
}
```

The error I receive is that `output.receive(5000)` returns `null`. I suspect a threading issue because I am not subscribing to the Flux and waiting for completion.

I have run a debugger in the Flux functions and see the message going all the way to the end with no errors or weirdness.

Comment: Any chances that you can share with us a simple project to play with? Thanks

Comment: Hi Artem, I've figured this out and will answer the question. It was a misunderstanding on my part I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out actually. I had to specify the binder name. I had a test property `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processingStream` set, which I thought made 2 new bindings (`processingStream-in-0` and `processingStream-out-0`).

It turns out I had to set the binding name in the test code like `output.receive(5000, "processingStream")`, without the `-out-0` suffix. I can now receive messages from the stream.